# .NET Core 2.0 (Preview) HTTPS endpoint error

Tags: asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express, preview

So I installed VS2017 v15.3 to try out the new .NET Core 2.0.
Created a new "Web Application" project with Individual Authentication option. Ran the project, registered.

Now it all seems to be fine, but then I tried to create a new class for my database, tried to add migration, and then I got the message:

> Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. For information on configuring
>   HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054

So I followed the steps on the documentation, but with no positive results.
I found out that IIS was not installed on my computer, so I added the feature in windows - so I can import a certificate as per doc. - but that doesn't work either.

I'm not new in VS, but I'm not really familiar with the configuration options.
Currently I managed to somehow mess up everything, and even on a new project when hitting Ctrl+F5 under IIS Express, I just get a "This site can’t be reached" error message.

Any advice please?

Comment: i face same issue. Is there any solution for this error?